# Multiple default images for carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Two models are sharing the same Carrierwave uploader class.

Carrierwave as a default_url method. How can I get it to return different results based on the class that called it? e.g:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


 def default_url
  return "https://www.example.com" + ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("main/profile/user_2.png") if CONDITION        
  "https://www.example.com" + ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("main/profile/user.png")
 end
```

Comment: Why not use 2 different Uploaders? I guess you used only one Uploader in the first place because both Models shared similarities. In your case, now, they don't have similarities, they are "divergent", so why trying to execute the same code for two distinct models which require a specific treatment?

Answer (score 3):

You can call model and all the methods that you need for example: model.class.name

```
 def default_url
  return "https://www.example.com" + ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("main/profile/user_2.png") if  model.class.name == "User"        
  "https://www.example.com" + ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("main/profile/user.png")
 end
```